# PHP - Load too much array data caused page not responding?

Tags: php, arrays, json, server, apache2

I don't know how to explain this but seems my live server have problem when I'm doing `json_decode(string_json, true)` with 61 mb json data.

I already try to look for maximum of array size on php but it's not help at all because I already set `memory_limit = -1` on my live server and the weird things I got is, this page have no problem at all when I load it on my local server.

Btw I already make sure that's the root of my problem because I just tried to comment out my line of code which is decode json and then my page is work.

so is there any way to solve this case? I already tried different browser and network but it's stay the same error and not when I comment out json_decode line.

[image]

Comment: *seems my live server have problem when I'm doing json_decode(string_json, true) with 61 mb json data.* ... 61MB JSON? There's got to be a better way of doing what you're attempting.

Comment: `seems my live server have problem when I'm doing json_decode(string_json, true) with __61 mb json data__.` You don't say!.... PHP arrays take lots of memory; there isn't documentation about the max size of an array, because you'll almost certainly run out of memory first; but this is a very large volume of data, and will certainly cause memory problems

Comment: Perhaps something like https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser might help

Comment: @MarkBaker I will try using it and about memory problem, I think it will have same result if I run on local. my live server have better specification than my local server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried increasing the max_execution_time for your script?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php